# Why is my query returning far to many results?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I have a bunch of candidates, who have had one or more jobs, each with a company, using some skills.

Bad ascii art follows:

```
         ---------------                              ---------------   
         | candidate 1 |                              | candidate 2 |
         --------------- \                             --------------      
           /              \                                 |
       -------              --------                        etc
       |job 1|              | job 2 |  
       -------              ---------  
        /     \              /      \  
  ---------   ---------  ---------   --------  
  |company |  | skills | |company | | skills |  
  ---------   ---------  ---------- ----------
```

Here's my database:

```
mysql> describe jobs;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| job_id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| candidate_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| company_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_date   | date    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_date     | date    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

.

```
mysql> describe candidates;
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| candidate_id   | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| candidate_name | char(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| home_city      | char(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

.

```
mysql> describe companies;
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| company_id        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_name      | char(50)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| company_city      | char(50)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| company_post_code | char(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| latitude          | decimal(11,8) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude         | decimal(11,8) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

.

```
mysql> describe skills;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| skill_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| job_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

.

```
mysql> describe skill_names;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| skill_id   | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| skill_name | char(32) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here's my attempt at a query (note, I intend to change the wildcards to field names; I am just trying to get something working):

```
SELECT can.* , co.*, j.*, sn.*
FROM candidates AS can
JOIN jobs AS j 
JOIN companies AS co ON j.company_id = co.company_id
JOIN skills AS s ON s.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN skill_names AS sn ON s.skill_id = s.skill_id
```

HediSql says  `/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 34,461,651  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. (+ 105.078 sec. network) */`

What's wrong with the query? I hope that it is clear from the bad ascii art what I am trying to achieve.

(also, does it make any speed difference which order I join the tables? I will worry about the new MySql v8 functions which retrieve it as nested JSON later)

Comment: Actually, sample data wouid greatly help your question.

Comment: In what way? I can post data, but it will be humorousness (and randomly generated). I am more than happy to help, just sure how it makes a difference, given the description of a bunch of candidates, who have had one or more jobs, each with a company, using some skills`.

Comment: How many rows in each table (at least approximately).

Comment: Currently? As stated, about 100 candidates with approx 5 jobs with approx 3 skills. In "real life", maybe 5k candidates, with 10 jobs with 20 skills. I will now auto-generate more ransom data & test. Currently 0.16 seconds after @GMS's excellent answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a join condition between `candidates` and `jobs`, so you get a cartesian product between both tables. Also, there is a problem with the join condition on `skill_names`, where both columns are the same (this again generates a cartesian product).

```
SELECT can.* , co.*, j.*, sn.*
FROM candidates AS can
JOIN jobs AS j ON j.candidate_id = can.candidate_id --> here: missing join condition
JOIN companies AS co ON j.company_id = co.company_id
JOIN skills AS s ON s.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN skill_names AS sn ON sn.skill_id = s.skill_id  --> and here: wrong join condition
```

Many RDBMS would raise a syntax error on a `JOIN` without an `ON` clause (if you do want a cartesian product, you need to be explicit about it by using `CROSS JOIN`), but, alas, not MySQL.

---

When it comes to this question:

> does it make any speed difference which order I join the tables?

No. As long as you are using `inner join`s (not `left join`s), the join order does not matter to the query planner, which will rearrange them in the order which it thinks is the more efficient.

Comment: `73479 rows in set (0.17 sec)` whoo hoo!!   I will double check the query with a smaller database, but am sure that you are correct, given your rep. Thanx a 1,000,000

Comment: I guess that I will ask 2 new questions & link to them form here : 1) does it make any speed difference which order I join the tables (that would improve my understanding)? 2) what about the new MySql v8 functions which retrieve it as nested JSON later

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: updated my answer for your question (1). Question (2) would need more information, and is probably worth a new question indeed.

Comment: an excellent answer, which ought to also help others in future. Thankyou

Comment: Can you help me with [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264812/refine-this-query/63336340)?